# HTML5: Drawing and upload image directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, image-uploading

I have a simple drawing page which has a drawing board and a upload button.

What i want is to allow users to upload their drawn image by pressing the button.

I know how to handle this from the database side.

I need help on the html or the front end side.

My html

```
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="280"></canvas>
<a id="download-canvas" href="#">Download</a>
```

My JS

```
(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c'),
        cxt = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        downloadLink = document.getElementById('download-canvas');

    cxt.fillStyle = 'red';
    cxt.fillRect(100, 50, 200, 200);
    cxt.clearRect(150, 100, 100, 100);

    downloadLink.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    downloadLink.download = "download.png";
})();
```

I want to make the download button to a upload button which can upload the file to a custom directory. Which parts should I change?

Comment: uploadButton.onclick = function() { uploadImage(); };

Comment: You won't get better answer than this without giving us some details about what you have on the client side.

Comment: Could you tell us something about the technologies you are using? could you show some code?

Comment: Please provide code for client side and other details as well so that it is easier for us on StackOverflow to try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an invisible form, and a button which triggers a click event on the invisible file input when it's clicked.

Your HTML

```
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="280"></canvas>
<a id="download-canvas" href="#">Download</a>
<!-- You may add an invisible file input -->
<form action="/url" method="post">
<input type="file" style="display:none">
<button id="upload">Select file</button>
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Your JS

```
(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c'),
        cxt = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        downloadLink = document.getElementById('download-canvas');

    cxt.fillStyle = 'red';
    cxt.fillRect(100, 50, 200, 200);
    cxt.clearRect(150, 100, 100, 100);

    downloadLink.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    downloadLink.download = "download.png";
    var button = document.getElementById('upload');
    button.addEventListener("click", showForm);


})();

function showForm(){
    $("#upload").click();
}
```